# How can I test my DNS and site configuration

Tags: windows, webserver, dns

I've received a few messages from users of my site that they can not access it from home.

They can access the server from the IP, but not by the domain name.

I think it has something to do with the way my DNS is configured. I setup my own DNS server about 4 years ago on my server, which I probably should not have done, and I'm not sure if everything is configured correctly. There are plenty of people who can access the site without any problems, but some users get 'server can not be found'.

Server Details: Windows 2003 co-located server at a small local hosting company.

Are there good tools or sites that can test and provide configuration recommendations? How do I test this problem when it works fine for me and so many other users? What type of questions should I ask users that can't access the site?

Can I provide / point to another DNS server that can be used if the first server isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs to ServerFault...

Answer (score 4):

Nevertheless here some pointers:

Questions that you can ask the users:

1. Run the following command: `nslookup test.company.com`. The result should be the IP they could access by IP. If it's a wrong IP or no IP, then this hostname `A` / `CNAME` record isn't propagated correctly to the outside world.
2. It could be a ipv4/v6 problem. Maybe the DNS resolves to a ipv6 IP by `AAAA` record and your ISP (or any provider inbetween) doesn't support ipv6 correctly yet. Under windows, you can `ping -6` or `ping -4` to see if it resolves to anything at all.

Possible workaround:

Tell your users to hardcode the IP of your server into their HOSTS file...

DNS problems are usually lying at the companies infrastructure though (e.g. not propagating the DNS notifications correctly, wrong DNS servers at your registrar, wrong DNS configuration on your DNS server...)

Comment: Thanks, helpful information, the question I have is how do I know that I don't have the wrong DNS configuration on your DNS server (since I configured this) if it is wrong would it work for some and not for others?

Comment: Hard to tell if I can't look into it myself :( Maybe the DNS configuration wasn't properly propagated to all DNS Servers due to some misconfiguration?. Does your company use some kind VPN? Since some VPN-Clients also switch the DNS servers on the client. Are the NS entries correct at your registrar (you can see them using whois)?

Comment: @leif also ask the users which provider and DNS server (`ipconfig /all | findstr DNS`) they're using.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like it is an issue with their DNS server, but I do not know why their DNS server would not find my domain. I contacted their ISP and they are able to access the domain and suggested that the user switch DNS server to either open DNS or Google DNS

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent on-line resource to verify your DNS settings: intoDNS.com

If you think the problem is in your DNS server and you don't need it this way anyway, you can just turn your DNS to any DNS hosting - see my [biased list](http://talkdns.info). Setup your DNS records from scratch with any DNS provider and tell your domain registrar to use that provider nameservers. Often registrars themselves provide DNS servers as well.

As for questions to ask users, Khoi explained everything.