# Getting NameOrService not known error when trying to load data to Data Lake Storage Gen1

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to load data to Data Lake Storage Gen1 using python but getting NameOrService not known. 
I have created an AD application and got the client key, tenant id as mentioned in docs

```
adlsAccountName = '*******'
adlCreds = lib.auth(tenant_id = '*****', client_secret = '*****', client_id ='******')
##Create a filesystem client object
adlsFileSystemClient = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name=adlsAccountName)
adlsFileSystemClient.ls('/')
```

The error i am getting is :

> azure.datalake.store.exceptions.DatalakeRESTException: HTTP error: ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='junipertest.azuredatalakestore.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/.?api-version=2018-09-01&listSize=4000&OP=LISTSTATUS (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",),)

I have tried mkdir and ls both but getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Name or service not known" is a network error that indicates the host cannot be resolved `junipertest.azuredatalakestore.net` or there is no service on port 443.

1. [Check the name again in the Azure portal.](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts)
2. [Check the name resolution (DNS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014158/how-can-i-test-my-dns-and-site-configuration):

> > nslookup junipertest.azuredatalakestore.net # Windows
>
> $ dig junipertest.azuredatalakestore.net # Linux

3. Ensure you have a route to reach the data lake.

   - From the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts) Select *Data Lake Storage* and the select *Firewall and virtual networks*
   - [For Gen1 storage, follow this guide to secure data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data)